# Sandcastle Help File Builder cannot find vs2010.config

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sandcastle, portable-class-library, shfb

I am trying to build documentation for a Portable Class Library (.Net40, Silverlight 4, .Net for Windows Store, Windows Phone 7.5) as HTML Help 1 and MS Help Viewer.  I only have one "Documentation Source".  The project is set to use the vs2010 documentation style (problem also exists with the vs2005 style).  Whenever I try to build the documentation project, whether through Sandcastle Help File Builder GUI or Visual Studio 2010, I always get the same error:

```
SHFB: Error BE0019: Unable to transform template 'VS2010.config': Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\.NETPortable'.
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\.NETPortable'.
```

After more investigation it looks like the directory should be `C:\Program Files (x86)\EWSoftware\Sandcastle Help File Builder\Templates\VS2010.config`.  How can I redirect SHFB to that directory instead of the directory it is trying?

What must I do to get the documentation project to build?

Through further investigation, I think I have deduced that this problem is with the documentation source being a portable class library.  Is this a bug in SHFB, or is it something I can fix myself?

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem and it seems copying the files from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETPortable\2.3.5.1` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\.NETPortable` solved the issue.

But I don't really understand what's going on and this doesn't feel like a proper solution to me, just a workaround.